# Why is my if statement ignored even after typing hello in input

Tags: arrays, c, string, if-statement, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[]=("hello");
    char b[10];
    printf("enter value: ");
    scanf("%s",b);
    if(b==a){
        printf("%s",a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when I run this code it shows me to 'enter value' as expected but when I enter 'hello' which is equal to variable 'a' it is not showing the if statement.

Comment: `b==a` is a pointer comparison, you want `strcmp`

Answer (score 1):

`==` will check that `a` and `b` are pointers to the same string in memory, which they aren't. To compare the **contents** of these strings, you can use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(a, b) == 0) {
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `scanf` to consume one line of input, write `scanf("%s\n",b);`.

Another point is that you want to compare buffer contents, instead of pointers. Use `strcmp` function in the `if()` clause.